# How to make use of splitter container in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, resize, splitter

I have a form where I display 3 DataGridView components like below:
[image]

I would like to be able to adjust all of them in such a way that when the form is resized it also grows/shrinks accordingly while keeping all of its content displayed (i.e. making the fonts smaller). It is also the case that this interface will be used in different computers with different size of screens, so I would like to adjust the whole interface to fit in the screen no matter what size it is.

I tried using the Dock Fill which works fine for only one fixed position on the adjusted computer, however does not work with a smaller screen (i.e. the screen is cut off in the middle of the completed machines DataGridView). Then I tried using Anchor for Top, Bottom, Left and Right, however I got the following when I resize the form:

[image]

I tried using both Dock Fill and Anchor for Top, Bottom, Left and Right which I thought could solve my problem but it is not possible to use them both at the same time for some reason.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using pair of nested splitter controls.  Insert the first, making one side 66% and the other 34%.  Then place the other splitter control (sized 50/50) into the 66% side (given that your grids aren't the same width, you'll need to adjust these, but you should get the idea).  Put one of your grids in each pane.  As to adjusting the font sizes, I think you are on your own with that

Comment: Could you explain it further, I have tried using the splitter but could not really manage using it to resize the grids

Comment: Drop a Splitter control on your form.  Set its `Dock` property to `Fill` so that it fills wherever you drop it.  Set its `Orientation` property to `Vertical`.  The `Size` property is a `(width, height)` tuple.  Take the width value and divide it by 3.  Use the result to set the `SplitterDistance` property.  Now you should have two panes, one twice as wide as the other.  Now drop a second splitter onto the wide pane.  Set it to `Fill` and `Vertical` and set its `SplitterDistance` to half the Size's `Width`.  At this point, you have three resizable panes (though the resizing is a bit odd).

Comment: Drop your grids into each pane.  If you run your app, and you resize the Form, the panes (and the grids) will resize 1/3 - 1/3 - 1/3.  In your case, you'll need to do more calculation than just 1/3 - 1/3 - 1/3.  That will get you part way there